# Computation of standard series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, fourier-series

I am stuck on the computation of the following sum:
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-n^2}\cos(n)$. Simple tricks fail and also i have no idea how to fit it for Fourier series. Are there any other ways?

Comment: Do you have any context at all? The numerical value is 0.19102186682951427854 and the inverse symbolic calculator has no idea about this constant.

Comment: No context at all, just exercise. Thanks for the explicit value!

Comment: are you really supposed to find the sum, or just prove convergence?

Comment: The convergence is obvious, because $\frac{|\cos(n)|}{e^{n^2}}\le \frac{1}{n^2}$. Really, i need the sum.

Answer (score 1):

I fear that you may write it only as a theta function.

\begin{align}
S:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2}\cos(n)&=-\frac 12+\frac 12\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-n^2+in}\\
&=-\frac 12+\frac 12\theta_3\left(\frac 12,e^{-1}\right)\\
\end{align}
using the definition of the $\theta_3$ [Jacobi theta function](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta3/) (see too [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html)) :
$$\theta_3(z,q)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}e^{2niz}$$
The [theta functional equation](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta3/16/01/01/0002/) allows to find a still faster convergent sum ($64$ digits with only $3$ terms) :
$$S=-\frac 12+\sqrt{\pi}\;e^{-\frac 14}\left(\frac 12+\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-\pi^2 k^2}\cosh(\pi\;k)\right)$$
and even with one term we have (to $15$ digits) :
$$S\approx -\frac 12+\sqrt{\pi}\;e^{-\frac 14}\left(\frac 12+ e^{-\pi^2}\cosh(\pi)\right)$$